# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns NULL except on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I've read all the answers on getting this to work but I still cannot get it to work on phones below iPhone 5.  On iPhone 5, all is well.  On iPhone 4 and 3GS, I get `NULL`.  No matter what I change, it does not seem to work.  My 3GS is running IOS 6.1.3.  I'm not sure what the 4's are running (as no one that has one is in yet).  My 5 is running 7.1.1.  I'm assuming this is where the issue is, but cannot find that being said anywhere.  However, if this is the case, is there another way I could do this if `date` is null?  My code is below.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];

NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-06-06T11:30:09-0400"];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There was a change in timezone support, but I can't recall the details.

Comment: there is no probelm on my side, it gives back a proper date in iPhone4, like `2014-06-06 15:30:09 +0000`. that seems correct to me.

Comment: @holex What version of IOS are you currently running on your iPhone4?

Comment: one of the my test devices is an iPhone4 with iOS7.1, I used that one.

Comment: @holex Thanks, I'm assuming this is the issue I have - that it's not compatible with older versions of IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after I finally posted this after looking forever, I did finally find the fix.  I simply needed to add 2 more `Z`'s.  My final format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`.

Comment: Officially you only need to do that if the zone has an embedded `:` character.  (And note that ZZZZZ is not a supported format on earlier versions.)

Comment: @HotLicks It does seem to work either way on IOS6 and 7 for me.  I did also read that it works on IOS5 but only if there is no colon.  But supposedly it was introduced in IOS6 from what I read (for the colon support?)

Comment: Yeah, the TZ support is pretty flaky, and it's usually safest to use ZZZZZ all around.